# Mirth - Waiting for a message from server before querying for data

Tags: hl7, mirth

I am new to Mirth (currently using version 2.2.1.56861)

I need to configure a client so that it does the following:

- Makes a connection to a server port
- Waits for a message (ORU^R01)
- Sends a QRY^R02 to the server

Is this possible in Mirth?

I have setup an LLP sender, but it appears the connection is made, the QRY^R02 is sent and then the connection is closed

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if you need to configure a "client", but it waits for a message, it is a "server" not a  "client".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you need is to set up a channel like this:

Source: `LLP Listener`

- Waits for server to connect to it and send an `ORU^R01` message.
- Other message types may be filtered out based on Source `Filter` criteria.
- May use `Transformer` steps to pull data out of the `ORU^R01` message for use in the `QRY^R02` message.

Destination: `LLP Sender`

- When a `ORU^R01` is received from `Source`, sends a related `QRY^R02` message to a server.
- Constructs the `QRY^R02` message using a series of `Transformer` steps operating on a `Message Template`.
- Does not need to send to the same port or even the same server as the `ORU^R01` message was received on.